# How to Alter the Structure of a File into a Tabular Format?

Tags: python, csv, formatting, format, tabular

I have a file contains the following data:

**Input:**

```
Query= A1 bird
Hit= B1 owl
Score= 1.0 4.0 2.5
Hit= B2 bluejay
Score= 10.0 6.0 7.0
Query= A2 shark
Hit= C1 catshark
Score= 10.0 7.0 2.0
Query= A3 cat
Hit= D1 dog
Score= 7.0 2.0 1.0
```

I want to write a program that manipulates the structure of data to make it in a tabular (.csv) format ... something like the following:

**Output:**

```
Query = A1 bird, Hit= B1 owl, Score= 1.0 4.0 2.5 #The first query, hit, score 
Query = A1 bird, Hit= B2 bluejay, Score= 10.0 6.0 7.0 #The second hit and score associated with the first query
Query = A2 shark, Hit= C1 catshark, Score= 10.0 7.0 2.0 #The second query, hit, socre
Query = A3 cat, Hit= D1 dog, Score= 7.0 2.0 1.0 #The third query, hit, score
```

I tried to doing the following suggested solution by [Takis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192085/1974919):

```
with open('g.txt', 'r') as f, open('result.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
fieldnames = ['Query', 'Hit', 'Score']
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, 
                           fieldnames=fieldnames)
csvwriter.writeheader()
data = {}
for line in f:
    key, value = line.split('=')
    data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    if len(data.keys()) == 3:
        csvwriter.writerow(data)
        data = {}
```

**Question:**
How to make the program recognizes the Hits and Scores associated with each Query, so I can print them in one line?  And if a Query has multiple Hits and Scores under it (associated with) print the query, the second Hit, and the second Score. Exactly like the following output:

```
"A1 bird","B1 owl","1.0 4.0 2.5" #1st Query, its 1st Hit, its 1st Score
"A1 bird","B2 bluejay", "10.0 6.0 7.0" #1st Query, its 2nd Hit, its 2nd Score
"A2 shark","C1 catshark", "10.0 7.0 2.0"#2nd Query, 1st and only Hit, 1st and only Score
"A3 cat","D1 dog","7.0 2.0 1.0"#3d Query, 1st and only Hit, 1st and only Score
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `DictWriter` class in the `csv` package to write the parsed data to CSV. There's no error handling, the program assumes the three needed data items will appear for each query, although they do not need to given in the same order for each query.

```python
import csv

with open('g.txt', 'r') as f, open('result.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Query', 'Hit', 'Score']
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, 
                               fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csvwriter.writeheader()
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split('=')
        data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
        if len(data.keys()) == 3:
            csvwriter.writerow(data)
            data = {}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That's very neat...I am still curious how to make the program recognizes the multiple occurrences of the "Hit" and "Score" lines under each "Query" line.  Is there away to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line

```
print line.rstrip("\n\r"), #print of the first score
```

to

```
print line.rstrip("\n\r") #print of the first score
```

(remove the last comma).

If you want to repeat the previous query, you need to add some variables:

```
query = None
prev_query = None

for line in file:
   if line.startswith("Query="):
      query = line.rstrip("\n\r")
      print query, #print of the query line
   elif line.startswith("Hit="):
      if not query:
          print prev_query,
      print line.rstrip("\n\r"), #print of the first hit
   elif line.startswith("Score="):
      print line.rstrip("\n\r") #print of the first score
      prev_query = query
      query = None
```

Comment: Great! Thanks!  Is there away to make the program outputs the query line again in a new line if it has another hit and score associated with it.  Like so:

  `A1 bird B1 owl 1.0 4.0 2.5`  <br/>  `A1 bird B2 bluejay 10.0 6.0 7.0`

Comment: That is working amazingly! I really appreciate you help ... One question if you do not mind ... How can we print the lines without `"Query="`, `"Hit="`, or `"Score="`  I tried to use `.split()`, but not sure how to incorporate it correctly into the code.